# Can you use your own Reference Data Service in DQS?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, data-import, data-quality-services

The requirement is to use a list of contacts in a spreadsheet (excel/CSV) and "merge" this data with a microsoft SQL table.

I've looked at Data Quality Services and i can't find a way to use my own Reference Data Service.

Is there any other way to use a spreadsheet to edit, update data in a Microsoft SQL server 2012 table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, DQS does not support using own reference data sets.